# Selenium currency fomat issue

Tags: java, selenium

I am using sendKeys to input the currency on the website. The input field has default value $0.00. When I input my value ($35462.02) through selenium, it shows as $0.0035462.02. I want to show as $35462.02.

Comment: Two approaches - 1. design the page to clear input on click, i.e. default value, 2. clear the input?

Answer (score 0):

You should try first  `.clear()` to clear the `input` and then `sendKeys()` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement....;
el.clear();
el.sendKeys("$35462.02");
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Clear didn't help. I had to do control A and then use send keys driver.findElement(By.id("invoiceItems0beginDate")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), invoiceData.get("START_DATE"));